# Facing difficulty when I try to fetch the Id for the CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

In my project I'am getting 30 requirement from the server. I have shown everything in a CheckBox. So based on the requirement size am creating the CheckBox inside the loop. I'am also setting Id for the CheckBoxes. Again I'am getting the Id from server and am setting the same Id to the CheckBoxes.

```
for(int i=0;i<require.size();i++)
    {
        //From Requirements
        requirement=require.get(i);
        RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        rl1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewdesign);
        l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        req1 = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        rl1.addView(req1);
        req1.setId(Integer.parseInt(requirement.r_id));
        Log.i("getid",Integer.toString(req1.getId()));
        li.add(Integer.toString(req1.getId()));
    }
```

Now the problem is out of 30 CheckBoxes just 2 CheckBoxes were checked. I have received the 5 CheckBoxes Id from the server. I also compared the 2 CheckBoxes Id with the above CheckBoxes Id. Here the problem is the second CheckBox is only setting true. The first CheckBox is not setting true(Out of 2 CheckBoxes). Am i doing wrong? please guide me.

```
for(int i=0;i<li.size();i++)
    {
        //li.get(i);
        req1 = (CheckBox) container.findViewById(i);
        String sr = req1.toString();
        for(int j=0;j<proj_require1.size();j++)
        {
            pr = proj_require1.get(j);
            if(sr.equals(pr.rid))
            {
                req1.setChecked(!req1.isChecked());
            }
            else
            {
                req1.setChecked(req1.isChecked());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't tryied to understand your code, but setting them checked when you are creating them would be much easier.

Comment: @user714965 I'am showing the requirements based on the kind of projects. Yes It is easy for retrieving single requirement based on single project. But if i have multiple projects then I have to show the requirement based on the projects. So this view generation with the checkbox have to change based on the different project

Answer (score 0):

On the following line:

`req1 = (CheckBox) container.findViewById(i);`

are you sure its findViewById(`i`); ? Instead of `li.get(i)` where `li` is apparently your array of Ids from the server.

i.e. try: `req1 = (CheckBox) container.findViewById(li.get(i));`

Also if your comparing Id to Id then also modify:

`String sr = req1.toString();` to `String sr = Integer.toString(req1.getId());`

Comment: If i give like this req1 = (CheckBox) container.findViewById(li.get(i)); then it asks me to change findViewById to findViewWithTag. So just i have wriiten like this final String dd=li.get(i);
    req1 = (CheckBox) container.findViewById(Integer.parseInt(dd));  But it is showing NullPointerException in this line req1.setChecked(!req1.isChecked());

Comment: Don't change it to Tag, its asking you to change it probably because `li.get(i)` returns a String and `findViewById(id)` receives an int. Use `Integer.parseInt(li.get(i))`

Comment: What about `container` ? What is container and did you add each of the RelativeLayouts to such container ? I see in the loop you create a pair of checkbox and RelativeLayout and place the Checkbox in the RelativeLayout but I don't see you placing the RelativeLayout somewhere else, maybe your missing that ?

Comment: container is a object of View.I didn't add with relativelayout